# I store the score by hole of a round of golf in a database. I want to write a function that sums that column in the table and displays in a toast

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is the function that I have created. The Playgolf table has columns id, holepar, strokes, putts. I'm looking to sum up the strokes.

I have edited the code to this and now I'm getting this error...any ideas?

```
public void DisplaySum(int sum)
{
    //Setup a local variable to store sum
    int intRoundsSUM = 0;
    db.open(); 
    //Setup your database cursor
    Cursor c = db.getPLAYGOLF();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), intRoundsSUM, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Iterate through the cursor
    //Sum up each value
   c.moveToFirst();
        while(c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            intRoundsSUM += c.getInt(2);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), intRoundsSUM, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
    // LOG CAT MAIN ERROR: 
    //E/AndroidRuntime(597): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa
```

Comment: looks like you are not actually fetching a row of the cursor.

Comment: Don't forget to close your cursor (unless it is not under activity managment).

Comment: If the exception is `ResourceNotFoundException`, then definitely the problem is not with the cursor. the problem is with the view element. Please post the error stacktrace or see in which line the error is pointing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage your cursor, start with

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
    intRoundsSUM += c.getInt(2);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Also read about letting your activity control the life cycle of the cursor with `activity.startManagingCursor(cursor);`

Comment: I added your code to my function and now I get this error....E/AndroidRuntime(597): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa

Comment: Strange, this error tends to happen when you reference something like `R.id.foo` where foo is not defined. Pleas post more of the logcat error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the cursor rows with the next cycle:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    intRoundsSUM += c.getInt(2);
}
```

But you can also try to make 'sum' selection from the database. Something like this:

`SELECT SUM(strokes_column) FROM golf_table`

It will return table with one column and one row that stores the necessary sum.

Comment: Excellent suggestions! And don't forget to call `cursor.close()` and `db.close()` when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Try `c.moveToFirst()` before `intRoundsSUM += c.getInt(2);` to fix the error.

To sum them all you can use `while (c.moveToNext())` or make a sum in your sql query (which would be better). See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

Answer (score -1):

There might be two reasons:

1. Playgolf table is empty. check the size by using `c.getCount();`
2. You are at the end of the cursor. use `c.moveToFirst()` to go to the beginning of the cursor.